# Bigquery is really slow for queries, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have seen demos where Bigquery crunches TBs of wikipedia data in 20secs but for me Its takes about min to process 6mb data. This table has about 180,000 rows

The query I am running is simple count & group by but it still took `57.9s`

Wondering if I am doing something wrong. not sure why its so slow?

`Job ID: circular-gist-812:job_nkVWH76gqCNjgXOlIGsvoMdI7pM`

[edit]

The query is

```
SELECT event_type,
             INTEGER(COUNT(*)) AS email_count
      FROM   [analytics_demo.email_events]
      WHERE object_id = 4090 and klass='FreePunchhCampaign'
      GROUP  BY event_type
      ORDER  BY email_count DESC
```

Comment: Can you paste the query?

Comment: Updated the post with the query

Comment: Is it always slow, or just occasionally?

Comment: Most of time its little slow(more than 15secs) & sometimes very slow(about a 60secs). We are currently evaluating Bigquery for building realtime analytical dashboards. Our team not happy with the results so far as it fails to perform as advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you ask if you're doing something wrong: no, you're not. And no, this isn't expected. We're trying to track down the issue; it seems there was a transient issue that lasted for a few hours on Sept 18 and slowed a small percentage of queries (but certain types of tables were more likely to have been affected, which is why you saw the issue repeatedly).

The number of queries affected was small enough that it didn't tickle our monitoring, but it is a high priority issue and we hope to prevent it from happening again in the future.

I'd expect that if you ran your queries again, they should probably execute in under 2 seconds. If you see times of more than a few seconds, however, can you let us know and post the job ids?

Comment: That makes sense. I tried again & issue is gone now. Thank you for responding.